# Why does repr() add escape characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, repr

From the below `clock` decorator,

```
import time
from functools import wraps

DEFAULT_FMT = '[{elapsed:0.8f}s] {name}({args}) -> {result}'

def clock(fmt=DEFAULT_FMT):
    def decorate(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args):
            t0 = time.time()
            result = func(*args)
            elapsed = time.time() - t0
            name=func.__name__
            args = ','.join(repr(arg) for arg in args)
            result=repr(result)
            print(fmt.format(**locals()))
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorate
```

`result=repr(result)` is adding escape `\\\` characters in output string, for below code,

```
from functools import lru_cache
from clock_package import clock

emptyRecrList = None

#Representation - start
#Constructor
def list(first, rest):
    return [first, rest]

def first(s):
    assert s != empty, 'empty linked list has no first'
    return s[0]

def rest(s):
    assert s != empty, 'empty linked list has no rest'
    return s[1]
#Representation - end


def fibSequence(k:int) -> list:
    prev, curr = 1, 0
    @lru_cache()           # applied last
    @clock()               # applied first
    def genSequence(prev, curr, k):
        if k == 0:
            return emptyRecrList
        elif k == 1:
            return list(curr, emptyRecrList)
        else:
            return list(curr, genSequence(curr, prev+curr, k-1))
    return genSequence(prev, curr, k)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fibSequence(11)
```

---

Expected output:

```
$ python3.6 fibonacci.py 
[0.00000167s] genSequence(34,55,1) -> [55, None]
[0.00007153s] genSequence(21,34,2) -> [34, [55, None]]
[0.00010061s] genSequence(13,21,3) -> [21, [34, [55, None]]]
[0.00012279s] genSequence(8,13,4) -> [13, [21, [34, [55, None]]]]
[0.00014472s] genSequence(5,8,5) -> [8, [13, [21, [34, [55, None]]]]]
[0.00016618s] genSequence(3,5,6) -> [5, [8, [13, [21, [34, [55, None]]]]]]
[0.00018954s] genSequence(2,3,7) -> [3, [5, [8, [13, [21, [34, [55, None]]]]]]]
[0.00021267s] genSequence(1,2,8) -> [2, [3, [5, [8, [13, [21, [34, [55, None]]]]]]]]
[0.00023627s] genSequence(1,1,9) -> [1, [2, [3, [5, [8, [13, [21, [34, [55, None]]]]]]]]]
[0.00026131s] genSequence(0,1,10) -> [1, [1, [2, [3, [5, [8, [13, [21, [34, [55, None]]]]]]]]]]
[0.00028825s] genSequence(1,0,11) -> [0, [1, [1, [2, [3, [5, [8, [13, [21, [34, [55, None]]]]]]]]]]]
```

Actual output:

```
$ python3.6 fibonacci.py 
[0.00000143s] genSequence(34,55,1) -> [55, None]
[0.00007296s] genSequence(21,34,2) -> [34, '[55, None]']
[0.00011134s] genSequence(13,21,3) -> [21, "[34, '[55, None]']"]
[0.00013995s] genSequence(8,13,4) -> [13, '[21, "[34, \'[55, None]\']"]']
[0.00016642s] genSequence(5,8,5) -> [8, '[13, \'[21, "[34, \\\'[55, None]\\\']"]\']']
[0.00019479s] genSequence(3,5,6) -> [5, '[8, \'[13, \\\'[21, "[34, \\\\\\\'[55, None]\\\\\\\']"]\\\']\']']
[0.00022340s] genSequence(2,3,7) -> [3, '[5, \'[8, \\\'[13, \\\\\\\'[21, "[34, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[55, None]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']"]\\\\\\\']\\\']\']']
[0.00025082s] genSequence(1,2,8) -> [2, '[3, \'[5, \\\'[8, \\\\\\\'[13, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[21, "[34, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[55, None]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\']\\\']\']']
[0.00027943s] genSequence(1,1,9) -> [1, '[2, \'[3, \\\'[5, \\\\\\\'[8, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[13, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[21, "[34, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[55, None]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\']\\\']\']']
[0.00030875s] genSequence(0,1,10) -> [1, '[1, \'[2, \\\'[3, \\\\\\\'[5, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[8, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[13, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[21, "[34, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[55, None]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\']\\\']\']']
[0.00034404s] genSequence(1,0,11) -> [0, '[1, \'[1, \\\'[2, \\\\\\\'[3, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[5, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[8, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[13, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[21, "[34, \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[55, None]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\']\\\\\\\']\\\']\']']
```

Why `result=repr(result)` add escape characters in the output string?

Comment: Could you share your current result?

Comment: @AnthonyPham Query edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that your `clock` decorator is changing the type returned by your function. I suspect you intend the line `result=repr(result)` to only effect the printing of the current line, but it's affecting later lines because when `result` gets returned, it's a string instead of a list. When it gets included in later results, the quotation marks conflict and Python starts using backslashes to escape them. Then it needs more backslashes to escape the previous ones, ending up with the mess you have shown.

Try using a different variable name for the `repr`'d result you `print` and for the unmodified result you `return`:

```
    def wrapper(*args):
        t0 = time.time()
        raw_result = func(*args)               # use a different variable name here
        elapsed = time.time() - t0
        name=func.__name__
        args = ','.join(repr(arg) for arg in args)
        result=repr(raw_result)                # convert to string for display
        print(fmt.format(**locals()))
        return raw_result                      # return the unmodified version
```

Answer (score 0):

The `repr` returns a string that -- when copy/pasted into a Python source code -- would create the same value. You may want to use `str` instead when you want to see a human-readable strings.